# 1 origin, multiple destinations, same google map v3 - error message

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As the title mentions, I'm trying to create one map that presents a single origin with directions rendered for multiple destinations (not waypoints). I managed to achieve this with tons of duplicate code. However, I want to consolidate the code into one reusable javascript object but having challenges, possibly with proper scoping of things?

Here is the error I encounter:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDirections' of undefined
```

Javascript code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
var directionsDisplay;
var map;
var route1 = new route();
var route2 = new route();
var route3 = new route();
var route4 = new route();

function initialize() {
  var austin = new google.maps.LatLng(30.2669, -87.7428);
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: austin
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function route() {
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  //alert(JSON.stringify(this.directionsDisplay));

  this.calcRoute = calcRoute;

  function calcRoute(end) {
      if (end === undefined) {
          end = "New York";
      }
      var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
      var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      this.directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(this.directionsService));
              this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
          }
      });
  }
}
```

HTML looks something like this:

```
<select id="loc1" onchange="route1.calcRoute(getElementById('loc1').value);">
<option value="123 Anywhere lane NY">my Address</option>
```

How do I resolve the error and display one map with one origin and multiple endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectionsService is subject to a quota and rate limits.  You can retrieve multiple routes if you handle the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT case and back off.

A couple of examples that do that:

- http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html
- http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html